# Query which finds all Objects which contains text

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, query-builder

I've following method, which should find all Objects with passed text="3":

```
private DBCursor queryForText(final String text) {

    Pattern searchPattern = Pattern.compile(text);

    DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().or(
            QueryBuilder.start(MMSI_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get(),
            QueryBuilder.start(IMO_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get(),
            QueryBuilder.start(NAME_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get(),
            QueryBuilder.start(CALLSIGN_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get(),

            QueryBuilder.start(TYPEOFSHIP_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get(),
            QueryBuilder.start(LENGTH_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get(),
            QueryBuilder.start(WIDTH_KEY).regex(searchPattern).get())
            .get();

    return getVesselsCollection().find(query);
}
```

My Problem is, that *TYPEOFSHIP*, *LENGTH* and *WIDTH* are from type `int`. So if someone enters a text = "3", those attributes won't get found because these are no Strings. I'm looking for a way to not distinguish by valuetypes, e.g. with typecasts? I've no clue how to continue, maybe i'm still not familiar with mongoDB.

EDIT:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/ there you see the relation between SQL and MONGODB. I think i need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_id like "%3%"
```

But `QueryBuilder` seems not to offer something like `like`.

Thats the JUnit test which I want to let work:

```
@Test
public void testSearchForTextt() {
    // Given
    VesselController controller = new VesselControllerImpl();
    controller.create("hugo", "bene", "2", "3", 4, 5, 6);
    controller.create(" ", "bene", "2", "3", 3, 6, 7);
    controller.create("3", "bene", "3", "hugo", 5, 6, 7);
    controller.create("3-name", "herbert", "Toto", "hugo", 5, 6, 7);

    proveAmountOfVessels(controller, 4);

    proveSearch(controller, "bene", 3);
    proveSearch(controller, "hugo", 3);
    proveSearch(controller, "3", 5);
    proveSearch(controller, "[", 0);
    proveSearch(controller, " ", 1);
}

private void ueberpruefeSuche(final VesselController controller, final String text, final int expectedElements) {
    // When
    Collection<Vessel> treffer = controller.findByText(text);
    // Then
    assertEquals(String.format("Wrong amount of elements '%s' found", text), expectedElements, treffer.size());
}
```

The relevant check is:

```
proveSearch(controller, "3", 5);
```

because there are different kind of datatypes it isn't working. My MongoDB command of the shown code above should look almost like this:

```
db.vessels.find({$or : ['mmsi' : {$regex : 'text'}],
['imo' : {$regex : 'text'}],
['name' : {$regex : 'text'}],
['callsign' : {$regex : 'text'}],
...
['width' : {$regex : 'text'}]})
```

> query: { $or: [ { mmsi: /3/ }, { imo: /3/ }, { name: /3/ }, {
>   callsign: /3/ }, { typeofship: /3/ }, { length: /3/ }, { width: /3/ }
>   ] }

I guess this should be the right Query! but I'm not sure, because the result isn't that what i've expected.

Comment: Text search searches strings. If you want to search a non-string field, you need to add an additional field with a stringified version of the original field and text search the new field.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a text search:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: It seems to go the right direction, anyway I've a problem. I'm using QueryBuilder to create Querys but there is no methode for 'text'-searches, Java is offering the methode 'regex' which seems almost similar to 'text'-search but I don't know if it's the same. Maybe anyone know where to find a very good description of QueryBuilder because I can't gain anything of the API.